# Hide other section of page when focus/zoom on particular div/element in angular5

Tags: css, typescript, chart.js, angular5, angular6

Trying to zoom/focus on one element/div and hide other

Please refer to the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/zoom-div-chart) at  I want to hide all the other sections of the page and zoom only particular div/chart which is being clicked.Tried fullscreen API but it is not working as expected.

Trying to achieve zoomooz plugin like functionality in Angular . Since npm does not support zoomooz. Is it possible to have same functionality i.e. animated zoom on click. I am using Angular 6 with ng2 charts and want to zoom the div/canvas section on click and back to normal

Comment: You didn't include any source, so the only answer you can possibly get is yes, it's possible.

Comment: Please refer to the demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/zoom-div-chart) at I want to hide all the other sections of the page and zoom only particular div/chart which is being clicked.Tried fullscreen API but it is not working as expected

Comment: @MrLister Please check this..